# Error TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:

Tags: laravel

Tengo un proyecto en laravel en mi local host funciona bien, al subirlo a un servidor web en linea me da el siguiente error: TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si comento la linea que me da el error el login me redirecciona nuevamente al login y no puedo acceder al sistema, alguien puede ayudarme a resolver este error?

Comment: Bienvenido Manuel... seria bueno que te des una vuelta por [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta... y ya que estamos, hablas sobre un código que modificas, seria bueno que lo incluyas para que nosotros podamos partir de algo y asi buscar el problema de forma mas facil...

Comment: Gracias por las recomendaciones,  revisare las políticas de las preguntas, donde puedo subir mi proyecto para que lo revisen?

Comment: @VíctorHugoTirado  crees que podrías revisar mi proyecto? Para pasarte los datos del servidor